# AJAX success handler not being invoked

Tags: ajax, jquery, playframework-1.x

I am trying to perform an AJAX request to a Play application on Heroku from my local machine. Currently, the `'complete'` and `'error'` handlers are being invoke but not the `'success'`. In Opera and Firefox, my response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Play! Framework;1.2.4;prod
Set-Cookie: PLAY_FLASH=;Expires=Fri, 5-Oct-12 08:22:46 GMT;Path=/
Set-Cookie: PLAY_ERRORS=;Expires=Fri, 5-Oct-12 08:22:46 GMT;Path=/
Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=;Expires=Fri, 5-Oct-12 08:22:46 GMT;Path=/
Content-Length: 2295
Connection: keep-alive
```

Opera also shows the returned JSON object

Here is my code:

```
var url = "http://myurl.com"

$.ajax({
    'complete': function (jqXHR, status) {
        console.log('Complete!');
        console.log(status);
        console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    'dataType': "application/json",
    'error': function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log('Error!');
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    },
    'success': function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    },
    'type': 'GET',
    'url': url
});
```

Other similar questions suggested changing the datatype to text or removing it altogether: neither work. I have successfully validated the returned JSON object at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

The console log is:

```
Error!
error

Complete!
error
```

I'm not sure if it is linked, but the `getAllResponseHeaders()` function is returning an empty string.

Is this a cross domain error?

Any help is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: `error` and `success` cannot happen together

Comment: I'm not surprised, but why is the `'error'` handler being called when there is no obvious error?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: Well `console.log(error);` returns an empty string, so i'm not sure, but I think the problem is cross domain? I should be using jsonp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840825/ajax-with-jquery-200-ok-but-not-success) they suggest  that it is indeed a cross domain error.